# Need solution for complex jquery validation logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation in my rails app.  I want to associate certain rules with certain triggers.  I am having trouble writing the logic.  I will try to explain what I want as clearly as I can.

Rules:

1. Maximum length of 25 characters.
2. Minimum length of 3 characters.
3. Characters may only be alphanumeric or whitespace.

Triggers:

1. The maxlength should only trigger on keyup.
2. The minlength should only trigger on submit.
3. Invalid characters should trigger onkeyup.

I am having trouble with the logic on how to get an invalid character to trigger on keyup when there are less than 3 characters.  The regex I was using for invalid characters is `/^[a-z\d ]+$/i`.

Here is my code:

```
$('#custom-tag').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else if (this.elementValue(element).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().length < 3)  {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },

    rules: {
      tag: {
        minLen: 3,
        maxLen: 25,
        format: true
      }
    }
  });
 });
```

Update:

I am trying to get this to work by adding a second validation to the same form.  The code is here:

```
$('.custom-tag-onkeyup').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },
    rules: {
      tag: {
        maxLen: 25,
        alphanumeric: true
      }
    },
    tooltip_options: {
      tag: { placement: 'right', animation: false }
    }
  });

  $('.custom-tag-onblur').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
                if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                  return;
                } else {
                  this.element(element);
                }
    },
    rules: {
      tag: {
        minlength: 3
      }
    },
    tooltip_options: {
      tag: { placement: 'right', animation: false }
    }
  });
```

I am adding two classes to my form so I can validate it two separate ways but it doesn't seem to be working.  It seems like only one validation will work at a time.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can check length manually on blur. Min Length check should not be on keyup

Comment: How would you do that?  A separate call to .validate?

Comment: I've never used jQuery validator plugin but simple answer would be yes. Idea is to check validity of individual character while user is typing and once he says I'm done typing, i.e. on blur, check for complete validity and length. Also instead of checking for max length, use maxLength property of textbox.

Comment: My javascript isnt' very good to be able to write this all from scratch.  The plugin makes it easy but I'm just have a difficult time figuring out how to satisfy all my rules/triggers as noted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are 2 approaches that you can try:

#### Approach 1

Per my comment, you can test value validity on `keyup` and length on `blur`. Issue with this approach is you will have to maintain 2 different error labels.

#### Approach 2

You can allow user to enter any data and validate on `blur`. Benefit of this approach is, you will validate only when user has completed typing and will ignore any typo-correction cases.

Both approaches are depicted in following [JSFiddle].(http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ynby1an8/)

#### Code

```js
function validateInput(el){
 var regex = /^[a-z\d ]+$/i;
  if(!regex.test(el.value)){
   $("#err_valid").fadeIn()
  }
  else{
   $("#err_valid").fadeOut()
  }
}

function validateLength(el){
 if(el.value.length <3){
   $("#err_length").fadeIn()
  }
  else{
   $("#err_length").fadeOut()
  }
}

$("#text2").on("blur", function(e){
 var regex = /^[a-z\d ]+$/i;
 if(!regex.test($(this).val())){
   $("#err_both").text("Invalid Data").fadeIn();
  }
  else if($(this).val().length < 3){
   $("#err_both").text("Enter at least 3 characters").fadeIn();
  }
  else{
   $("#err_both").fadeOut();
  }
})
```

```css
.error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" onkeyup="validateInput(this)" onblur="validateLength(this)" maxlength=25>
<p class="error" id="err_valid">Invalid entry</p>
<p class="error" id="err_length">Enter at least 3 characters.</p><br/>

<input type="text" id="text2">
<p class="error" id="err_both">Invalid entry</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please see my update.  I am trying to work with your first approach because I want functionality as I described at the start of my question.

Comment: It looks like what I want to do is [not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346150/jquery-validate-separate-rules-for-separate-events?noredirect=1#comment56434476_34346150) with this plugin.  I will have to write from scratch if I want this type of functionality.  Thanks for the input.