# Jquery validate - separate rules for separate events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I can't figure out how to apply separate rules to separate events with the jquery validation plugin.  I have custom rules.  I want maxLen and formatVal to validate on keyup but I want minLen to validate on submit only.  How can I achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {



$.validator.addMethod(
    "maxLen", 
    function (value, element, param) {
      var value = this.elementValue(element).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
      if (value.length > param) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }, "Please enter no more than {0} characters");

$.validator.addMethod(
    "minLen", 
    function (value, element, param) {
      var value = this.elementValue(element).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
      if (value.length < param) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }, "Please enter at least {0} characters"); 

  $.validator.addMethod(
    "formatVal", 
    function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\d ]+$/i.test(value);
  }, "Letters and numbers only");




  $('#custom-tag').validate({
    debug: true,
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            var validator = $('#custom-tag').validate();
            if ( this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                validator.resetForm();
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },

    rules: {
      tag: {
        maxlength: 7,
        formatVal: true
      }
    }
  });



  });
```

Jsfiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/s6nas4gu/1/

Comment: Can you think of any type of work around or any possible way I can achieve this?

Comment: If I knew of a workaround, I'd post it as an answer.  This is simply a limitation of the plugin.

Comment: How would I achieve this without the plugin?

Comment: What about adding a minlength rule on submit event with .rule()?  Then I would need a way to remove it to mimic the functionality I want...

Comment: It's too late within the `submitHandler` because the form is already valid when this fires.  Writing your own `submit` handler is no good either because it will interfere with the plugin.  Your best best would be to write your own validation function and not use this plugin.

Comment: Thanks very much @Sparky!